# Trying to make "Contact detaills" buttons through modals on a site, but keep getting the same "modal content" for each one

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

Two individuals contact details needed, I've set up a picture and a short description, under which are "contact details" for each of them. Set these up with modals but I'm having difficulty in making the modals content i.e their actual contact details individual for each modal box. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please upload your code

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. Take help of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to

Answer (score 0):

You need to update modal content on each button click before the modal shows.
You can do this using bootstrap event `show.bs.modal`

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  //Your code to update modal body
})
```

- Reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events